# what happened when set jruby min runtime?

Tags: jruby, tomcat6, warbler

I am now struggle on Jruby on Rails. We did not config the min/max jruby runtime before, the portal works well.

In these days, i found that set these config will improve our portal's performance, so I decide to config it in this way:

```
config.webxml.jruby.min.runtimes = 2
config.webxml.jruby.max.runtimes = 4
```

However, we portal can not boot up after i setting this, the log continue throw the java class can not found error:

```
INFO: Info: received max runtimes = 4
Dec 19, 2012 1:57:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: received min runtimes = 2
Dec 19, 2012 1:57:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Info: received max runtimes = 4
Dec 19, 2012 1:57:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: An exception happened during JRuby-Rack startup
cannot link Java class com.portal.util.selector.SelectorUtil, probable missing dependency: Could not initialize class com.portal.util.selector.SelectorUtil
--- System
jruby 1.6.1 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) (2011-04-12 85838f6) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_35) [linux-amd64-java]
Time: Wed Dec 19 13:57:18 +0000 2012
Server: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
jruby.home: file:/var/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home
```

What is the difference when we set this min/max jruby runtime? Anyone can get me out of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any one can help me out this???

Comment: `Could not initialize class com.portal.util.selector.SelectorUtil` suggests that you're missing a JAR that should have this class. Do you have it?

Answer (score 0):

[jruby thread safe comparison](http://jrubytips.com/posts/3-enable-threadsafe-for-rails)

in config/warbler.rb

```
config.webxml.jruby.min.runtimes = 1
config.webxml.jruby.max.runtimes = 1
```

and in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.threadsafe!
```